# Sending XML in SOAP with PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm want to send the following XML file to http://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2010-11-01/ldb/commontypes" xmlns:typ="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/[put your version here]/ldb/types">
```

```
  <com:AccessToken>

     <com:TokenValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</com:TokenValue>

  </com:AccessToken>
```

```
  <typ:GetDepartureBoardRequest>

     <typ:numRows>10</typ:numRows>

     <typ:crs>MAN</typ:crs>

  </typ:GetDepartureBoardRequest>
```

But I'm not really getting anywhere, nearest I get to any data is a HTTP Error 405

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the native [SoapClient](http://php.net//manual/fr/class.soapclient.php) class in order to send a SOAP request? It requires that you define the WSDL path. Then each parameter can be sent with an array or objects.

In order to ease you all this you could use a WSDL to php generator such as [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp) at [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com/)